# Odour plume environment in Webots

Tags: ros, webots

I am new to Webots. I am trying to recreate odor source localization but don't know how to represent an odor plume in Webots. Need some help here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To represent (visually) your plume in Webots you will have to use the Supervisor API to import/move/modify object.

You can find an example in this simulation with imports an indexedLineSet and then modify it to draw the path of a robot:
https://cyberbotics.com/doc/reference/supervisor#wb_supervisor_node_add_force

Here is the source code (it is in C, but the same is available in C++, Python ROS, etc. too):
https://github.com/cyberbotics/webots/tree/master/projects/samples/howto/controllers/supervisor_draw_trail

Comment: Thanks. This code is what I was looking for. But I can't find the C++ code, can you please share its link too?

Comment: This sample is not available in C++, but the Webots API is available in C++ too:https://cyberbotics.com/doc/reference/supervisor?tab-language=c++#wb_supervisor_node_add_force
So you should be able to quite easily translate the sample.

Comment: I'm actually trying to create a plume from a source other than the robot like how its shown over here. Should I follow the same method that you suggested before and how should I approach this differently?

Comment: Yes, you should in any case have a robot using the Supevisor API if you want to interact with the simulation, but of course this robot can be 'empty' (i.e. have no appearance and bod).